# Can't unlock bootloader or go to download mode in Samsung Galaxy M11

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, bootloader-lock, download-mode

I have Samsung Galaxy M11 (SM-M115F/DS). I want to install TWRP in it. But I can't unlock the bootloader or go to download mode. I already enabled OEM Unlock.

I saw on some sites that on this device I have to press both volumes up and down to go to download mode or unlock the bootloader but actually, nothing happens. It only goes to recovery mode with power and volume up. There it has a "Reboot to Bootloader" option.

[image]

When I go there, I get this

[image]

When I give the options to start, I return to recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have backed up your files because all of your data will be wiped.
2. Make sure that adb and fastboot are installed on your PC.
3. Download the TWRP image file.
4. Enable USB debugging from developer mode.
5. Connect your phone to your PC and open cmd.

Enter the following command:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Or simply go to fastboot mode (like what you did in the second picture). Then connect your phone to the computer and open cmd (if you already didn't).

Type the following command and hit enter

```
fastboot flashing unlock
```

If you got an error, try this command (used for older phones):

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

If you get a confirmation screen on your device, press the Volume Up button to highlight Yes and press the Power button to select it. This will begin the bootloader unlocking process, which shouldn’t last more than a couple of minutes.

Then again, reboot to bootloader. Type following command:

```
fastboot flash recovery <path to your twrp image file>
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know but i have the samsung m12. In adb you should do

```
adb reboot download
```

or

```
adb shell
reboot download
```

thats how i got it to work on my m12

Maybe this is useless but when flashing such images flash the `vbmeta.img` too maybe to be safe. I dont know.